# If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A^2)$. True by the spectral theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a symmetric $m\times m$ matrix. Can I say $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A^2)$ is true by the spectral theorem?

My reasoning is as follows:

- The spectral theorem states that every real, symmetric matrix is
  diagonalizable.
- This means $A = P^{−1}DP$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $P$ is some invertible matrix.
- To calculate $A^2$, the diagonal matrix would just be raised to $2$: $A^2 = P^{−1}D^2P$

Intuitively, all that is changing is the diagonal matrix. It makes sense that the rank/nullity would not change, but I'm not exactly clear why.

Comment: Hint: the rank of a diagonal matrix is the number of non-zero elements on the diagonal.

Comment: @David ...which isn't changing when the diagonal matrix is squared, hence it remains the same as the original. It seems like I can extend this logic to a matrix raised to *any* power—not just 2. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks right to me :)

Comment: As long as you’re talking about real matrices, yes.

Comment: An alternate proof not needing the spectral theorem: $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A^T A)$ since it's straightforward to show the two have equal null spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can conclude that $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A^2)$ by the spectral theorem.

Since $A$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable. Thus, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A = P^{-1}DP$. Because $D$ is diagonal, $D^2$ is also diagonal, so
$$A^2 = P^{-1}D^2P = P^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1^2 & & \ & \ddots & \ & & \lambda_m^2 \end{pmatrix} P.$$
Since $P$ is invertible, the rank of $A$ is equal to the rank of $D^2$, which is equal to the rank of $D$, which is equal to the rank of $A^2$. Thus, we have $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A^2)$.